# How to properly handle the version field in a JPA entity with Spring Data

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a very simple domain model, one entity which has a version field in order to use the optimistic locking capabilities provided from JPA (api v2.2). The implementation i use is Hibernate v5.3.10.Final.

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Activity {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "gen", sequenceName = "gen_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "gen")
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String state;

    @Version
    private int version;
}
```

Then there are simple operations with that entity, like for example temporarily changing its stage:

```
@Transactional
public Activity startProgress(Long id) {
    var entity = activityRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new);

    if (entity.getState() == "this") { // or that, or else, etc
        // throw some exceptions in some cases
    }

    entity.setState("IN_PROGRESS");

    return activityRepository.saveAndFlush(entity);
}
```

The outcome of this, what i'd like to achieve, is to have a way to update the entity, and that update should also increment the version. If there is a mismatch, i'd expect a `ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException` or `OptimisticLockingException` to be thrown. I'd also like to have the updated value of the `version` field in the object, as i'm returning it to the client.

Several options which i've tried:

- simply call `save` - the version field gets updated, but the new value is not returned and the client gets the old one, which makes the next request hit the locking exception
- call `saveAndFlush` - in this case i get the update statement on the client executed twice, which weirdly returns version X which in the database the version is X+1. Then again the next client request hits the locking exception.
- Create a `@Modifying` query, mark it as clear automatically (to auto flush the change) and use the hql `create versioned` syntax. Then i get the following query executed: `update activities set version=version+1, state=? where id=?`, but this doesn't seem to do the optimistic lock check (`where version = :version_from_entity`). I also don't think it will raise the appropriate exception.

So, in the end what i'd like to achieve is quite simple and i don't think i have to write it on my own - have a way to update one or more fields on a versioned entity, rely on JPA for the optimistic locking and get the latest version so the client can do further operations with the entity. I read quite a lot of similar issues but most use the entity manager directly, which is not what i'm striving for.

Comment: The version should get updated automatically. Are you using the correct `@Version`annotation from `javax.persistence`?

Comment: Yes, the `javax.persistence` and not the one from spring data commons.

Comment: I try `saveAndFlush()` in my local and cannot reproduce your mentioned problem. It works as expected and no more double update happen......So in your case, what are these two UPDATE SQL look like ? Are they the same ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks pretty correct so it's difficult to say where is the problem...

I've created a simple working [example](https://github.com/Cepr0/sb-sd-optimistic-lock-demo) with Spring Data JPA and Optimistic locking. I hope it will be helpful for you to solve the issue.

Create an entity:

```java
@Transactional
public Model create(Model model) {
    return modelRepo.save(model);
}
```

Update the entity:

```java
@Transactional
public Optional<Model> update(int id, Model source) {
    return modelRepo
            .findById(id)
            .map(model -> modelMapper.apply(model, source));
}
```

Get entities:

```java
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public List<Model> getAll() {
    return modelRepo.findAll();
}
```

Just clone the project, run it (for example, with `mvn spring-boot:run`), and check the log:

```
15:44:35.905  INFO 2800 --- [ main] i.g.c.d.Application : [i] Creating...
15:44:35.925  INFO 2800 --- [ main] jdbc.sqltiming      : batching 1 statements:
1:  insert into model (name, version, id) values ('model', 0, 1); {executed in 1 msec}
```

```
15:44:35.930  INFO 2800 --- [ main] i.g.c.d.Application : [i] Updating...
15:44:35.934  INFO 2800 --- [ main] jdbc.sqltiming      : select model0_.id as id1_0_0_, model0_.name as name2_0_0_, model0_.version as version3_0_0_ from model model0_ where model0_.id=1; {executed in 0 msec}
15:44:35.939  INFO 2800 --- [ main] jdbc.resultsettable : 
|---------|------|--------|
|id       |name  |version |
|---------|------|--------|
|[unread] |model |0       |
|---------|------|--------|
15:44:35.944  INFO 2800 --- [ main] jdbc.sqltiming      : batching 1 statements:
1:  update model set name='model_updated', version=1 where id=1 and version=0; {executed in 1 msec}
```

```
15:44:36.010  INFO 2800 --- [ main] i.g.c.d.Application : [i] Getting...
15:44:36.015  INFO 2800 --- [ main] jdbc.sqltiming      : select model0_.id as id1_0_, model0_.name as name2_0_, model0_.version as version3_0_ from model model0_; {executed in 0 msec}
15:44:36.017  INFO 2800 --- [ main] jdbc.resultsettable : 
|---|--------------|--------|
|id |name          |version |
|---|--------------|--------|
|1  |model_updated |1       |
|---|--------------|--------|
```

---

A few recomendations, if you don't mind )

Use an object instead of a simple type for `version` property (eg `Integer`, `Long`, etc). It's useful, for example, when you create entity identifiers yourself. In this case, Spring Data/Hibernate check that `version` is `null` and won't do an extra select query to the database.

When you update an entity you don't have to explicitly call `save` methods of the repo - since you are in a transaction the Hibernate update the changed entity itself.

Comment: Okay, but in your example you update the entity and then read it back in separate transactions. Do you properly get the version to be 1 at the end of the `public Optional<Model> update(int id, Model source)` method?

Comment: @MilanMilanov Check the log again - I've updated the answer a little...

Comment: Okay, i'm officially out of ideas. I changed the method to not call `saveAndFlush` and left Hibernate to take care of the update. Tests are still green, but amazingly it doesn't work in the real setup, an Oracle DB. Here's what the log says:

Comment: `SQL - select ... from activities act0_ where act0_.id=?
BasicBinder - binding [1] as [BIGINT] - [117]

SQL - update activities set state=?, version=? where id=? and version=?
BasicBinder - binding [1] as [BIGINT] - [117]
BasicBinder - binding [2] as [VARCHAR] - ["IN_PROGRESS"]
BasicBinder - binding [3] as [INTEGER] - [113]
BasicBinder - binding [4] as [BIGINT] - [117]
BasicBinder - binding [5] as [INTEGER] - [112]`

Clearly the version is updated from 112 to 113, but still 112 is returned at the end of the method, then to the client and again the exception happens.

Comment: The only Oracle specific thing used is the creation of the datasource, done using [PoolDataSourceFactory#getPoolDataSource](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/e11990/oracle/ucp/jdbc/PoolDataSourceFactory.html#getPoolDataSource__). Other than that the setup is identical with the one in the tests. Any ideas would be welcome as to why the behaviour might differ.

Comment: @MilanMilanov Did you run my project? Can you set it up to work with Oracle DB instead of H2 and check the result?

Comment: I did, yours works with Oracle as well. And damn, based on the differences in the two setups, i think i saw it. In order to work with domain objects only, at the end of my method i use a mapper, so the code is actually `return ActivityMapper.INSTANCE.toActivity(entity);`. I now believe this copies over the old version, then at the end of the method the transaction is flushed and the entity is modified, but not the resulting domain object. Does this mean i have to work with entities in the service layer? Is there a standard approach to tackle this then?

Comment: @MilanMilanov The algorithm is very simple: 1) start transaction; 2) read the entity from DB by its ID; 3) change ITS properties; 4) commit transaction. That's all. Regarding DTOs and entities in the service layer - I prefer the following way: the Service takes 'request' DTO from the Controller; converts it to the entity (with a Mapper); works with DB through a Repository; converts the result from the entity to 'response' DTO (with Mapper); return the result DTO to Controller. You can check an example in my [Generic CRUD](https://t.ly/nz83r) library. Glad I could help. )